# Calculate the minimum amount of billing hours

Tags: java, algorithm

Let's say I'm implementing a method that calculates the number of hours I'm billing a client. I only work in blocks of `K` hours:

```
public static int billing(int hours, int k) {
    return hours / k + (hours % k != 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Is it possible to simplify this? I often find myself writing this same pattern of code but it somehow bothers me.

I could think of

```
public static int billing(int hours, int k) {
    return (int)Math.ceil((double)hours / (double)k);
}
```

but I'd prefer staying in the realm of integers if possible.

Comment: What about `(hours+k-1)/k`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the integer operations available on a typical CPU, there's really no way to do it other than to determine whether the remainder is 0 and conditionally round up if it was not.

However, since you often find yourself using this pattern, write it once.  Not limited to "int hours", but the integer equiv. of ceiling, dividing but rounding up.  Then you can use the clearly named function when you need it, *and* the code is only in one place so if you find a way to determine that the remainder is non-zero that's faster than actually doing the division, you can change it in one place.

Note that since you are doing the division *anyway*, and the CPU instruction (on x86 at least; most work this way) deliver the div and remainder simultaneously, the optimizer should only do the operation once and get the remainder for free.  A fancy number-theory way of finding out whether the remainder is non-zero (without caring what it actually is) would only be more operations to perform.

---

Oh, I remember how I used to do it back in the day:  Add one less than the denominator and that will force it to round up, but if the result would have been exact you didn't add enough to increase it at all.

`return (hours+k-1)/k;`

Again, if you encapsulate this with "ceiling division" call, you can figure out which was is faster and the code is only in one place.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "didn't add enough to increase it at all"? I don't see why that formula shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, adding one less than the divisor is the standard way to get upwards-rounding division.  Do be aware that the intermediate value could overflow where the plain division would not - in most cases, this is unlikely to be a practical problem, but it could be a concern when values are close to the limit of `int`.

Comment: @danzel  if `hours` is a multiple of `k`, adding `k-1` will not increase the total enough to change the (truncated) quotient.

Comment: @JDlugosz that's exactly the expected behaviour. If `hours` is a multiple of `k`, the expected result is `hours/k` (not `(hours/k)+1`).

Comment: @danzel Of course it is; that's why it's a useful way to do it -- it gives the right answer.